# Cannot find and add SurfaceUserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I can create UserControl and add TextBox very easily in Surface environment. Here is a sample code:

```
   <UserControl x:Class="ScatterViewSizingSample.FixedSizeChild"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                 
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"         
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScatterViewSizingSample"
         mc:Ignorable="d" local:PopupWindow.InitialSizeRequest="300,250"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="250">
<Grid Background="MediumSeaGreen">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
   </UserControl>
```

I tried to add SurfaceUserControl and SurfaceTextBox, but I cannot find to add   SurfaceUserControl from the menu. I changed UserControl to s:SurfaceUserControl and Texbox   to s:SurfaceTextbox as follows:

```
    <s:SurfaceUserControl x:Class="ScatterViewSizingSample.FixedSizeChild"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"    
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScatterViewSizingSample"
         mc:Ignorable="d" local:PopupWindow.InitialSizeRequest="300,250"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="250">
<Grid Background="MediumSeaGreen">
    <s:SurfaceTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBox1"/>
   </Grid>
 </s:SurfaceUserControl>
```

But the system shows error that 'the type s:SurfaceWindows does not found'. I added Microsoft.Surface.Presentation and Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic assembly reference. But it still shows error.

How can I fix it? Why the system does not show SurfaceUserControl as UserControl?

Comment: this code looks fine.  what's the *actual* error message?  don't paraphrase it for us.  if there are multiple error messages, provide them all.

Answer (score 0):

An application using Surface controls needs to use SurfaceWindow as it's root visual in order to do all of the custom touch handling. I suspect that since you're trying to convert this you are probably still using a standard Window which is giving you this error.

Comment: that wouldn't explain this error.  it's totally legit to have a XAML file with SurfaceUserControl as the root element

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for 2.0, SurfaceUserControl no longer exists, as per MSDN:

*The SurfaceUserControl class has been removed in Surface 2.0. The SurfaceUserControl class was needed in Surface 1.0 SP1 to add touch support to user controls. However, touch support has been added to the UserControl class in .NET Framework 4. To convert your code, remove "s:Surface" from the front of "s:SurfaceUserControl", or use the Surface Migration PowerToy.*

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg697151.aspx#User)